# Combing input from two files in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I've read a bit about `awk`. It's proven to be extremely useful for single data Suppose I have two input files:

```
## inp1
x y
1 3
2 4
6 9
... 

## inp2
x z
1 5
2 19
6 9
```

I want to output something that 'combines' both files. Something like:

```
## output
x y z
1 3 5
2 4 19
6 9 9
```

I can think of ideas like interleaving these two files, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011814/how-to-interleave-lines-from-two-text-files and doing something with awk.

Or maybe something using associative arrays?
I'm not too sure however, which is the reason for this question ;).

I am using Linux.

Comment: There are some cases that should be explicitly stated, such as: what should happen if inp1 has a line for x=4 and inp2 does not, or vice versa; and if one file (or both) has two lines for x=7?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I agree, and not only that. It was not explicitly stated if the files should be "combined" using the `x` column (or should it be the first column, regardless of the header?). I hope I am not being pedant, but I think otherwise the problem is not quite defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're simply looking for `join` to join the files on the first field:

```
$ join -j1 file1 file2 
x y z
1 3 5
2 4 19
6 9 9
```

Note that `join` expects its input to be sorted, so you might need to do:

```
$ join -j1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2 )
1 3 5
2 4 19
6 9 9
x y z
```

However, that will screw up your header, so to avoid that you coud do:

```
$ join -j1 <(head -n1 file1) <(head -n2 file2); join -j1 <(tail -n+2 file1|sort) <(tail -n+2 file2 |sort )
x y z
1 3 5
2 4 19
6 9 9
```

And to save that to a new file:

```
( \
    join -j1 <(head -n1 file1) <(head -n2 file2); 
    join -j1 <(tail -n+2 file1|sort) <(tail -n+2 file2 |sort ) \
) > newFile
```

---

Alternatively, with `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}{print $1,$2,a[$1]}' file2 file1 
x y z
1 3 5
2 4 19
6 9 9
```

Comment: I'd prefer the awk answer... Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

With the sample input you provided all you need is this if the fields are tab-separated:

```
$ paste file1 <(cut -f2 file2)
x   y   z
1   3   5
2   4   19
6   9   9
```

or this if separated by a single blank:

```
$ paste -d' ' file1 <(cut -d' ' -f2 file2)
x y z
1 3 5
2 4 19
6 9 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

- Method 1

  ```
  awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$2;next}{print $1,a[FNR],$2}' f1 f2
  ```
- Method 2

  ```
  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];a[FNR]=$2;next}($1 in a) {print $1,a[FNR],$2}' f1 f2
  ```

Output

```
x y z
1 3 5
2 4 19
6 9 9
```